# how to wrap an expression in a function in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Good day, how can I wrap this expression in a function?
Expression is:

```
dict_ip = defaultdict(lambda: {"GET": 0, "POST": 0, "PUT": 0, "DELETE": 0, "HEAD": 0})


with open(args.logfile) as file:
     for index, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
        try:
              ip = re.search(regul_ip, line).group()
              method = re.search(regul_method, line).groups()[0]
        except AttributeError:
               pass
        dict_ip[ip][method] += 1

print(json.dumps((f"Requests by method: {dict_ip}"), indent=4))
with open("final_log.json", "w") as jsonfile:
    json.dump(dict_ip, jsonfile, indent=5)
```

Comment: Add `def my_function():` above the code and indent it

Comment: You are showing an entire block of several statements. What is the specific expression? Seeing how you define at least one function in there, what problem do you have wrapping whatever-expression-you-ask-about in a function?

Comment: Do you know how to define a function at all?

Comment: Not really, I'm just a beginer in python.

Comment: So your question is actually "how to define a function"?

Comment: No, it's just that in this case, adding def my_function () and then running the code leads to nothing.

Comment: Well, what exactly do you expect to happen? Wrapping the code in a function will create a function containing the code. It won't actually *run* the function. If you want the code to be run directly, don't wrap it in a function.

Comment: Thank you, but here's what I would like to achieve: this code is an attempt to write a parser for Apache access.log. In the resulting json file must be:  total number of requests from the log,  number of requests by method, top 10 ip, top 10 requests with error 200. I plan to wrap each of these parts of code in a function for better structure

Comment: So, wrap it in a function, then call it where appropriate. Apologies if this is seems snarky, but your original code already defines a function and calls a dozen - you seem to already be doing what you are asking about. Did you do the basic Python tutorial at python.org so that the terms are clear to you?

Comment: Don't apologize). I just started learning python and the manager has already asked me to run far ahead). thanks for the explanation